# I can't iterate through data gotten from firestore which I moved into an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore

I fetched my database from firestore and I wish to render all my users in a table. I got all the users data from the database and stored in an array, but each time I try to map through,I see an empty array with 0 length, whereas there are elements inside the array.

This is the code for fetching data from firestore

```
componentDidMount(){
        let allUser = []
        firestore.collection('user').get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                allUser.push(doc.data())
            })
        }).then(console.log(allUser.map((item, i) => console.log(item))))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error))
    }
```

Comment: have a check otherwise it will crash the app before you map the `array`,  ```allUser && allUser.map((item, i) => console.log(item))))
        ```

Comment: can you please explain ?

Comment: `console.log(doc.data())` ? what does it show?

Comment: it shows all the data in my firebase database

Comment: How exactly are you observing that the array is empty with 0 elements?  Please edit the question to be specific.

Answer (score 0):

You are building correctly your allUser array but then you map it with a `console.log`, but the `console.log` does not explicitly return something so you delete your objects by returning undefined for each item.

[image: ![enter image description here]

As you can see here, your `console.log` transforms your array into a collection of `undefined` elements. 
Just `console.log` your data (if you need this) in your forEach loop..

Comment: The question is saying that the array is empty and size 0, not that the array is size 3 with undefined values.

Comment: @DougStevenson that's right, but I find the description confusing: "I see an empty array with 0 length, whereas there are elements inside the array", bit of a  contradiction here imo.. and since console  logging doesn't return anything I assume this is the issue, but I might be wrong and will delete this answer if so, thanks for pointing this out though I somewhat missed this ¯\_(ツ)_/¯